# Send Complex XML through Ksoap2 in Android

Tags: android, xml, soap, ksoap2

I have spent over 10 hours looking for a solution to send this correctly through KSoap. I feel as if I've tried everything. What is the best way to build this XML in Ksoap2 and best way to post it?

I'm not even worried about parsing the response yet, just need to make sure I get a response.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:_5="http://clients.mindbrain.com/api/0_5">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <_5:GetStaff>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <_5:Request>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <_5:SourceCredentials>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <_5:SourceName>NAMENEEDED</_5:SourceName>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <_5:Password>NEEDED</_5:Password>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <_5:SiteIDs>
              <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
              <_5:int>IDNEEDED</_5:int>
           </_5:SiteIDs>
        </_5:SourceCredentials>
     </_5:Request>
  </_5:GetStaff>
</soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```